# 2.8 When and how should I remove unseen vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices

version 2.8 from March 19, 2019.

When building a shape, when and how should I delete vertices that are no longer necessary?

From two cylinders, a cube and a sphere, I built:

[image]

I have other questions on texture 'zooming', but this part of the object looks like this from the vertices:

[image]

So my question is: is there a way to combine these shapes into one object to 'naturally' eliminate all resulting unseen vertices/faces? I'm trying in 'Edit mode' or 'Object mode' or... ?? If there isn't a natural way, then how should they be combined and then how to eliminate the unseen stuff?

I've tried to follow other posts but all are old and the menu items don't exist or the directions say 'do this' but not how that actually works. If there's a specific tutorial to follow, then great! But the Blender course just stacks things so far and doesn't 'join' them.

Comment: To create a clearer question you can mark with a different color the vertices that you would like to delete.  3 minute or less operation.

Comment: "*how should I delete vertices that are no longer necessary*" You should not create vertices that are not necessary in the first place. Blender is not a CAD application, and Booleans should be used very sparingly. You should strive for [proper topology](https://topologyguides.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion.  Archive you current file so it becomes your old file.  Get a fresh start and create a  new file. You may soon forget about the old file.

[image]

Composed from pieces with no excessive or time consuming vertex editing.  Mesh sequence in image. Top Left Gray UV Sphere.  Quarter sphere highlighted, result of quick edit.  Yellow top mesh is composed of 4 quarter spheres, duplicated, rotated 180 degrees and translated along an axis [XYZ].  Bottom row yellow mesh show edges joined with 2

[Bridge edge loops] ... there are many video tutorials on this

Cyan mesh show 4 [Bridge edge loops] with some edge color with the goal of more readability.  You may examine and verify and optimize these steps.  You can change the proportions in edit mode by grabbing [left, right] or [top, bottom] vertices.

---

[image]

Simple Yellow Cube.  Cyan form begins as cube,  modified with many loop cuts and a proportional edit.  All edges showing.  Image above.  Bevel Modifier is a possibility.

---

Start with a cube. The cube is already a closed well formed object and you can enhance it.  Add bevels or loop cuts and use proportional edit.  All of these terms can be researched here at BSE or the typical other locations you seem to have previously explored.  Your fresh start will be easier and quicker than the old file.

---

[image]

Torus Option. Image above.

- Top Gray Mesh Torus with Bevel in four places on 2 global axis [XY].  Your axis may be different.  Bevel <kbd>Control B</kbd>. Note the dark vertex density in four places.
- Top Yellow Mesh.  [Push Pull] along a global [X] axis.  Select to vertical rings and invert selection then Push Pull.
- Top Cyan Mesh.  [Push Pull] along a global [Y] axis.  Select to horizontal rings and invert selection then Push Pull.
- Bottom yellow left mesh.  Delete inner faces. Only edge remains.
- Bottom Cyan Mesh. [Grid Fill] on top edge hole. You may find it useful to hide the other vertices for this operation.
- Bottom yellow right side mesh.  Side View.

---

I am not 100% clear on what you are trying to create but that in not 100% necessary.
There are always 33 ways to model something in Blender, some better and easier than others.  Your starting point in the question above is not a great learning sequence .  The older file seems to be creating a difficult and unnecessary stumbling block.

You might use Boolean operation, but that is a poor choice.

Comment: Yup - that's basically what I ended up doing; create the piece sections beforehand. But dummy me, I shoulda just copied them and rotated after just making one as you did... lol Thanks!

Comment: Please do not call yourself a dummy. At least yet while you consider yourself a beginner.   Blender will provide endless opportunities to learn from a mistake and curse Blender and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you find you have separate objects (instead of separate bits of mesh which are all one object) you should investigate the Boolean Union operation.  Assuming all your objects to start with were well formed closed meshes, this should result in one well formed closed mesh with a surface describing the union of space enclosed but both/all of the source meshes.

Of course, it has its own downsides, since the geometry formed can be rather complex and it also sometimes does odd things with closely overlapping geometry, but it's always worth a try if you're attempting to compose several shapes together and then do something with a unified surface from them.